# Any way of stop repeating while exporting functions in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a small API for fun in express, there's any way i can stop repeating e.g module.exports or usuariosControllers?

```
module.exports.getUsuarios = (request, response) => {};

module.exports.crearUsuario = (request, response) => {};

module.exports.getUsuario = (request, response) => {};

module.exports.eliminarUsuario = (request, response) => {};

module.exports.getOrdenes = (request, response) => {};

module.exports.crearOrden = (request, response) => {};

module.exports.getOrden = (request, response) => {};

module.exports.modificarOrden = (request, response) => {};
```

Comment: `module.exports = { getUsarios: ..., ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
module.exports = {
  getUsuarios: (req, res) => { 
     //something 
   },

  crearUsuario: (req, res) => {
  },
  //continue in this manner
}
```

Comment: This is about the least repeating you can get.  The newer module format would let you just use the `export` keyword, but this might even be more succint.

Comment: Thank you man! Also, when i import that module it's possible to import all methods from an object e.g const { ** } = require(module); rather than doing const { getUsuario, ...... } = require(module);

Comment: You can just simply avoid destructuring and require the object as it is. Then access any of the properties by simply addressing the key. For example: const controllers = require('module')  controllers.method(). Mark this as the correct answer if this helped you so others can see this.

Comment: Done! Thanks again